# Scala: SBT Eclipse plugin fails to build Breeze from scalanlp.org

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sbt, scala-ide, scala-breeze

I am new to Breeze (http://www.scalanlp.org/) and Scala in general. Please help to generate
Eclipse project for Breeze with sbt. I have Eclipse plugin for sbt installed.
When I try `sbt eclipse` it fails with the following errors. What is
wrong?
Thanks!

```
> ~/Distrib/Scala/breeze-master>sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/an/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/an/Distrib/Scala/breeze-
master/project
[info] Set current project to breeze (in build file:/home/an/Distrib/
Scala/breeze-master/)
> eclipse
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[error] java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
> last
...
...
[debug] Project dependencies for configuration 'compile':
Success(List(breeze-math))
[debug] Project dependencies for configuration 'test': Success(List())
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:274)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:272)
    at com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.Eclipse$.relativize(Eclipse.scala:
498)
    at com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.Eclipse$$anonfun$srcEntry
$1.apply(Eclipse.scala:252)
    at com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.Eclipse$$anonfun$srcEntry
$1.apply(Eclipse.scala:249)
    at scalaz.effects.IO$$anon$3$$anonfun$pure$1$$anonfun$apply
$23.apply(IO.scala:118)
    at scalaz.effects.IO$$anon$3$$anonfun$pure$1$$anonfun$apply
$23.apply(IO.scala:118)
    at scalaz.FreeFunctions$$anonfun$return_$1.apply(Free.scala:181)
    at scalaz.FreeFunctions$$anonfun$return_$1.apply(Free.scala:181)
    at scalaz.Pure$$anon$19$$anon$2.apply(Pure.scala:76)
    at scalaz.Functor$$anon$15$$anon$45.apply(Functor.scala:84)
    at scalaz.Free$class.go$1(Free.scala:73)
    at scalaz.Free$class.run(Free.scala:76)
    at scalaz.Free$Gosub.run(Free.scala:18)
    at scalaz.effects.IO$class.unsafePerformIO(IO.scala:13)
    at scalaz.effects.IO$$anon$2.unsafePerformIO(IO.scala:113)
    at com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.Eclipse$.onSuccess(Eclipse.scala:149)
    at com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.Eclipse$$anonfun$action
$4.apply(Eclipse.scala:105)
    at com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.Eclipse$$anonfun$action
$4.apply(Eclipse.scala:105)
    at scalaz.Validation$class.fold(Validation.scala:7)
    at scalaz.Success.fold(Validation.scala:82)
    at com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.Eclipse$.action(Eclipse.scala:105)
    at com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.Eclipse$$anonfun$eclipseCommand
$2.apply(Eclipse.scala:81)
    at com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.Eclipse$$anonfun$eclipseCommand
$2.apply(Eclipse.scala:81)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply
$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply
$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply
$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply
$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:90)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:
71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:
71)
    at sbt.State$$anon$2.process(State.scala:170)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:64)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:53)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:50)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:50)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:33)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:13)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:55)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in sbteclipse: https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/issues/128

You can try commenting out the "doc" project in the Project.scala definition and see if that helps. Otherwise, I think this is a bug in sbteclipse that has to get resolved first.

Comment: Thanks! Commenting out the "doc" project in the Project.scala allowed plugin to create projects in other dirs.